# Defining stubs in an RSpec helper method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, devise, devise-confirmable

I've got a confirmable `devise` model that I'm trying to write a spec for, and it's got some code that skips the confirmation if we're in a staging or development environment. To test it, I'm trying to stub the `Rails.env.*?` environment methods, so I defined a method as a helper to handle all the cases:

```
def enable_environment(env)
  if env == :staging
    stub_env('STAGING', 'true')
  end

  # clear all environments
  allow(Rails.env).to receive(:test?) { false }
  allow(Rails.env).to receive(:development?) { false }
  allow(Rails.env).to receive(:production?) { false }

  # turn on environment of choice
  if env == :production || env == :staging
    allow(Rails.env).to receive(:production?) { true }
  elsif env == :development
    allow(Rails.env).to receive(:development?) { true }
  elsif env == :test
    allow(Rails.env).to receive(:test?) { true }
  else
    raise 'no such environment'
  end
end
```

However, it's looking like these stubs are only scoped to the method--if I call `enable_environment(:staging)` in an example and debug with `byebug` right after, `Rails.env.test?` returns `true` and `Rails.env.production?` returns `false`. `ENV['STAGING']` also returns `nil`. Is there any way to do this, or will I just have to copy-paste the code in each example?

**Edit**: So, the second layer of the problem seems to be another scoping issue. I was testing by calling `User.create`, which calls my `skip_conf!` method off the `after_create` hook. This fails because the `Rails.env` that I've stubbed doesn't affect that hook (it seems).

Next, I tried just building a `User` model with `User.new` then directly calling `skip_conf!` on it. This fails because `skip_conf!` has side-effects (I get a `NoMethodError: undefined method '+' for nil:NilClass`). I've tried other methods (`skip_conf`, for instance, without side-effects), and they work. My `User` model looks like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_create :skip_conf!

  # ...

  def skip_conf!
    self.confirm unless (Rails.env.production? && !ENV['STAGING'] == 'true') || Rails.env.test?
  end
end
```

New testing code:

```
context 'in testing' do
  before :each do
    @user = User.new(
      # params
    )
  end

  it 'shouldn\'t skip confirmation' do
    allow(Rails).to receive(:env).and_return(ActiveSupport::StringInquirer.new('development'))
    @user.skip_conf!
    expect(@user.confirmed?).to be_falsey
  end
end
```

If I change `user.skip_conf!` to `user.skip_conf` (and write an empty `skip_conf` method in my `User` model), the test runs. Any ideas? I'm fine with just running this as an integration test if necessary, but I feel like it shouldn't be difficult to test a simple method with side-effects in RSpec.

Comment: You are using `user` and `@user`, shouldn't it just be `user`?

Comment: whoops, yeah, thanks. i had messed around with that a bit. fixed now, but still the same issue. wasn't failing on that line.

Answer (score 0):

What about stubing `env` on `Rails`, not `test?` etc. on `env`.

```
before do 
  rails_env = "test".inquirer
  allow(Rails).to receive(:env).and_return(rails_env)
end
```

Comment: I got there eventually (see my edit) but it seems like that's not the root of my problem